# Use a Command to set a property on another control all in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, .net-4.0

This seems like it should be simple.  But I could not find any matching questions so here it goes:

Say I have a button:

```
<Button>Press Me</Button>
```

And I have a third party tab control

```
<SomeTabControl x:Name="myTabControl" IsSelected="False">
   <TextBlock>Stuff Here</TextBlock>
</SomeTabControl>
```

How could I wire up the Command for that button so that it sets `IsSelected` to True for `myTabControl` using **ONLY XAML**?

Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Press Me" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myTabControl}"
                PropertyName="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

This requires that you add a reference to the `microsoft.expression.interactions.dll` assembly to your project.